# Spiting up text ,adding it to table

Tags: java

I got problem I try to split up text (orginal format is city#country#capitalcityname for example: Krakow#Poland#Warsaw) how can I split up text after # ? 
I want to put text after it into a table, is list a good idea ?

```
public class WordSearch {
ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<>();
    public WordSearch(){

        try {

             File file = new File ("songs.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = null;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(line);
//            System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }   
       public ArrayList<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

To make it more clear I add visual example of table
[image]

Comment: Have a look at StringTokenizers

Comment: @d_ominic: why are you recommending a class that even Oracle recommends that you not use? You almost always would use `String#split(String regex)` instead.

Comment: To the original poster, what do you mean by a "table"?

Comment: My bad, wasn't aware StringTokenizers were deprecated.

Comment: If you want a "table"-like structure, you should probably make a separate class called Song or something, and have the following instance variables: String city, country, capitalCityName. Then you just maintain an array of Song objects.

Comment: Hovercraft I edited my post to make clear what I want to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `split()` method:

```
 String s="Krakow#Poland#Warsaw";
  String[] parts = s.split("#");
```

The output :

```
for (String i: parts)
    System.out.println(i);
```

==>

```
run:

Krakow
Poland
Warsaw

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `split()` method.

```
String[] list = text.split("#");
```